# Graphing perpendicular vectors to a 3D graph

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I am brand new to mathematica,
I was wondering how can one obtain a curve similar to this one :
Where the vectors are perpendular .
Thanks for your help

the curve is $f(x,y) = \sin(xy)$

[image: sin(xy)]

Here is the code i currently have :

````
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi},
PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "f(x,y)"},
MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Red}},
Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False]

grad = Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}]
normal = Normalize[grad]
perpendiculars = Cross[normal, {0, 0, 1}]

VectorPlot3D[perpendiculars, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -1, 1},
VectorPoints -> Fine, VectorScale -> Small,
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, -1 <= z <= 1],
VectorStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.01]}]```
````

Comment: Please see the Applications section of the documentation for `VertexNormals`. It is a good idea to read the documentation and search this site before posting a question. Furthermore, please paste Mathematica code so that respondents can copy and paste it to their notebook sessions and study/resolve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my post, here is what i did

Answer (score 2):

You need the 3D gradient, not the 2D. Consider your surface as given by:

```
z-Sin[x y] == 0
```

Then the gradient perpendicular to the surface is given by:

```
Grad[z-Sin[x y],{x,y,z}]
```

With this we get (where we scale the arrows for graphical reasons):

```
f[x_, y_] = Sin[x y];
pl1 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "f(x,y)"}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
   MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Red}}, Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False];

normal = Normalize[Grad[z - Sin[x y], {x, y, z}]];

pl2 = Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.02], 
    Table[Arrow[{{x, y, f[x, y]}, {x, y, f[x, y]} + 
        0.5 normal}], {x, -Pi, Pi, Pi/10}, {y, -Pi, Pi, Pi/10}]}];

Show[pl1, pl2]
```

[image]